# me está dando el siguiente error Error Code: 1415. Not allowed to return a result set from a function

Tags: mysql

[image: código de la función]

Aparentemente no me da ningún error al lanzar la función pero después me da el siguiente error

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes un SELECT solito? Después del else

Comment: Justo lo acabo de ver jajaja, debería de ir otro return imagino, no?

Comment: La esctructura del ELSE deberia ser la misma, si

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero, un saludo

Answer (score 1):

El problema creo es de sintaxis, hay un "select" que no calza en la función debería ser un return

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE FUNCTION `mayormenor` (a int, b int) RETURNS VARCHAR (50)
DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN 
IF (a>b) THEN 
  RETURN concat(a, ' es mayor que ', b, '.');
ELSEIF  (a<b) THEN RETURN concat(a, ' es menor que ', b , '.' );
ELSE RETURN concat(a, ' es igual que ', b, '.');
END IF; 
END $$
```

Una aclaracion el llamado a Procedimientos almacenados es distinto a el llamado a funciones.

```
 Call mayormenor(5,3); 
 SELECT mayormenor(5, 5);
```

En este caso debería ser :

```
 SELECT mayormenor(5,3)
```